# Running cronjob in custom linx container on Azure App Service

Tags: linux, azure, cron, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I'm running an instance of [Strapi](https://strapi.io) in a container deployed on Azure App Service. My setup has Strapi using a SQLite database that I want to periodically backup to a storage container also on Azure. To do this I have included installation steps for AzCopy and cron into my Dockerfile. I also copy in various configuration and bash scripts including an entry point script to start the various services when the container comes up, a backup script to run the copy commands to do the actual backup and a crontab file to run that script periodically. At the moment this is set to every 5 minutes while I test but eventually will be daily.

No matter what I try the crontab job does not run when deployed to App Service but works perfectly when running locally. It's definitely the crontab as I can manually run the same command and the backup proceeds and writes output to the log file as it's supposed to.

I've ruled out cron not running, the command `service cron status` returns `cron is running.` My logfile remains empty unless I manually trigger the backup script, are there other log files that would give me a clue to any problems with cron?

backup-cron

```
*/5 * * * * sh /usr/local/src/sqlite/dailyBackup.sh >> /var/log/backup.log 2>&1
# An empty line is required at the end of this file for a valid cron file.
```

dailyBackup.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

. /tmp/.env

DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
DATETIME="$DATE $(date "+%T")"
SAS_URL="$SAS_PATH/data-$DATE.db$SAS_TOKEN"

echo "$DATETIME Creating local backup"
cp /usr/local/src/sqlite/data.db /usr/local/src/sqlite/data-$DATE.db 
echo "$DATETIME Copying local backup to Azure"
azcopy cp /usr/local/src/sqlite/data-$DATE.db $SAS_URL
echo "$DATETIME Removing local database as data-$DATE.db"
rm /usr/local/src/sqlite/data-$DATE.db
```

entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Copy environment variables to temp file for access via corn
echo SAS_PATH=$SAS_PATH >> /tmp/.env
echo SAS_TOKEN=$SAS_TOKEN >> /tmp/.env
# Get environment variables to show up in SSH session
eval $(printenv | sed -n "s/^\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)$/export \1=\2/p" | sed 's/"/\\\"/g' | sed '/=/s//="/' | sed 's/$/"/' >> /etc/profile)
# Start SSHD Process
sed -i "s/SSH_PORT/$SSH_PORT/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/usr/sbin/sshd
## Start Cron and App
service cron start && yarn start
```

Comment: Based on the above description, we understood that you CRON need to run for every 5 minutes then you corn expression will be
`0 */5 * * * *`.
CRON expression is composed of six fields -> {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}

[Reference documentation]-(
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#cron-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Did you map a volume to your container? in that case the backup method can be done over SMB or with Azure Logic apps.

this can be found in "configuration" in the left menu of your resource and than the "Path settings" tab.